# How to import external webpack modules dynamically?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to import webpack modules from an external url dynamically to a js app which is compiled with webpack itself.

Is it possible? If so how to do it in the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. webpack needs the files to be stored on the filesystem before it can work with them. https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/

Comment: It's not possible using webpack.  It might be possible to async load an external bundle into the scope though.